# Emacs -- incorporating a semicolon command line argument into elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

Inasmuch as the semicolon is a comment delimiter in `elisp`, is there an alternative method to incorporate a command-line argument (containing a semicolon) into an `elisp` function?  The command line works fine in the terminal, but I am at a loss regarding how to use it as part of a function containing a `start-process` statement -- Emacs doesn't recognize closing parentheses / quotes following the semi-colon, and Emacs naturally complains when loading.

```
ssh user@server -t "cd /some/directory; bash --login"
```

Here is a link to the related thread that provided the working command-line:  https://superuser.com/a/250538/206164

Here is the command-line argument that will eventually be incorporated into a function containing `start-process`.  Of all the variations I tried this afternoon / evening, the following command-line is the only one that works successfully in the terminal to log in to the iphone and go to a specific directory in one fell swoop -- i.e., `username@server.name:/path/` does not work on the iphone.  When everything is up and running, the start-process will be used in conjunction with `rsync` to synchronize one-way.

```
/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/elpa/bin/sshpass -p 'alpine' ssh -p '2222' -l root localhost -t "cd /var/mobile/Applications/F30B1574-5979-4764-8742-7F9DB2863094/Documents/.0.data; bash --login"
```

Comment: What does your call to `start-process` look like? Are you sure you didn't leave some double-quotes un-escaped inside a string?

Comment: @phils -- The start-process function that needs to incorporate rsync is not yet working, but here is a draft:  `(start-process "rsync-process" "*rsync*" "/usr/bin/rsync" "--dry-run" "--delete" "-arzh" "/Users/HOME/.0.data/" "--rsh=\"/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/elpa/bin/sshpass -p 'alpine' ssh -p '2222' -l root localhost\"" "-t" "cd /var/mobile/Applications/F30B1574-5979-4764-8742-7F9DB2863094/Documents/.0.data && bash --login")`

Comment: Are the last two args being passed to ssh or to rsync? In any case, if I change your `&&` to `;` I don't see any problems with Emacs reading the overall expression. (I'm running Emacs trunk from 2014-05-03.)

Comment: @phils @ Hmmm . . . you are right -- it does work now with the semicolon.  I must have made an error before with one or more of the quotation marks; however, I didn't keep the old draft.  As to rsync, I really have no idea how to make it work -- it works fine with two local directories -- there are no examples I could find on Google that deal with a remote target over ssh, just a remote source.  The simple version looks like this from the command line:  `/usr/bin/rsync --dry-run --delete -arvzh --progress /Users/HOME/.0.data/ /Volumes/DATA/OFFICE/06_28_2014`

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that ssh made a difference. Are you saying you can successfully transfer in one direction, but not in the other?

Comment: That is a good idea -- I'll try the other direction with the remote server (over ssh) as the source.  I've only been able to get it working locally in each direction, but not yet over ssh in either direction.

Comment: @phils -- it turned out that the Cydia on the iPhone has an rsync binary that needs to be installed, and that is the reason my connection over ssh kept getting broken by rsync.  So, I'm now in the home stretch!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised that this doesn't work as is since Emacs strings can certainly contain semi-colons, but if it's causing trouble you should be able to modify the command to use `&&` instead of `;`:

```
ssh user@server -t "cd /some/directory && bash --login"
```

This command will only run `bash --login` if the `cd` is successful, indicated by a return value of 0. I believe that this is your intention.

See Bash's [lists of commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists) documentation for details. (All other non-Windows shells that I'm familiar with also support this syntax).

Comment: Note that you shouldn't ever use a semicolon to chain together commands unless you *want* the subsequent command(s) to still execute if a preceding one failed. In most situations it's desirable for an error to abort the whole sequence, so you should get into the habit of using `&&` by default.